# Loop does not work properly, when the body is changed to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following loops works as intended and prints 0,1,2,3 to the console,

```
for(var x=0; x < 4; x++){
    console.log(x);
}
```

However, the following loop only (which is made to have same functionality as above) prints the last element i.e., 3 in the div with id s. No matter what changes I make to the conditions or the initial value of x or even change the loop entirely to while loop, same output is seen. What mistake am I doing here?

```
for(var x=0; x < 4; x++){
    $("div#s").html(x);
}
```

Comment: You are _overwriting_ the HTML content of the same element multiple times, of course only the last value you set “survives” that.

Comment: Okay got it.. Thank you.